# How can I get a progress report from an async write to an output stream?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx, iasyncoperation

In my app, I have to write an `IBuffer` to an `IOutputStream`. I'd like to show my user the progress of this operation, so I'm trying with the following code:

```
auto writeOp = strm->WriteAsync(buff);
writeOp->Progress = ref new AsyncOperationProgressHandler<unsigned int, unsigned int>(
    [=](IAsyncOperationWithProgress<unsigned int, unsigned int>^ op, unsigned int progress)
{
    MyViewModel->Insert("WriteProgress", progress);
});

auto writeToFileTask = create_task(writeOp);
writeToFileTask.then([this](unsigned int c)
{
    (void)c; // Unused parameter
});
```

However, `MyViewModel->Insert("WriteProgress", progress)` is never reached when I set a breakpoint. I don't know what I'd do differently to get this to work and I can't use C++/WinRT, so, any ideas?

Comment: Did you find out the reason why MyViewModel->Insert("WriteProgress", progress) was never reached?

Comment: Sadly no. I've given up on this since, I guess the operations are either fast enough to complete without reporting anything, or simply don't report correctly.